# Сравнение ли это?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Объясните, пожа-а-алуйста, почему постановка запятой на месте вопросительного знака является ошибочной. Это совсем не сравнение?

Пример взят из фантастической повести:

***«Солнце поднялось выше. Всё (?) как у людей, но всё иначе».***

Comment: Что с чем сравнивается? По-моему, "все" - подлежащее, "как у людей"  - сказумое.

Comment: Это не сравнение.

Answer (score 3):

В примере, который вы приводите, оборот с союзом как является не сравнительным, а составным именным сказуемым, поэтому запятая не нужна.

**Ср.: Снег у крыльца как песок зыбучий (Ее); Брызги и волны были как в жизни (Фед.);
Жизнь как легенда; Ты мне будто песня; Как ребенок душою я стал (Т.); Мы с ней словно родные сестры; Ручей по весне что река; Глаза у нее будто озера;**

> См.: Академический справочник. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь имеет место не сравнение, а *приравнивание* составного именного сказуемого "как у людей" подлежащему "всё". Между подлежащим и сказуемым не должно быть запятой.